# xpath to get Text() from a div when I have multiple subtags

Tags: xpath, text

I have a `tag` as below:

```html
<div class="popupContent">
  <div class="gwt-HTML">
    <h1 class="v-Notification-caption">Session Expired</h1>
    <p class="v-Notification-description">
      Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here</u> or press ESC key to continue.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need to read the full text using simple `xpath`.

when I tried using below:

```
//*[@class='v-Notification-description'][text()]
```

I am getting only

> "Take note of any unsaved data, and "

. How can I retrieve full text.

Comment: Provided description is incorrect as `[text()]` predicate can not return any text! Share correct XPath/description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string) function in order to produce the computed string value from all of the `text()` nodes in the selected `p` and it's descendants, in this case the `u` element.

```
string(//*[@class='v-Notification-description'])
```